# PLS-00371 AND ORA-06550 During a variable declaration

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have this problem trying to use the DATE variable that I declared in the beginning of this
code ,

```
DECLARE
  VID VARCHAR2(200);
  VFEC_CREACION DATE;
  VFEC_EXPIRACION DATE;
  FECHA_CREACION DATE;
  FECHA_EXPIRACION DATE;
  VESTADO_MENSAJES NUMBER;
  THISCURSOR PKGTEST.USR_SP_FUNCIONALIDADES.tCursor;
  ID_UNICO VARCHAR(200) := 'C56a418065aa426ca9455fd211123320223'; 
  FECHA_CREACION DATE := to_date('2020-01-19','yyyy-MM-dd');
  FECHA_EXPIRACION DATE := to_date('2020-01-20','yyyy-MM-dd');
 
 
BEGIN

    DECLARE
      VID VARCHAR2(200);
      VID_TOKEN VARCHAR2(200);
      VID_USUARIO VARCHAR2(200);
      VFEC_CREACION DATE;
      VFEC_EXPIRACION DATE;
      VUSU VARCHAR2(200);
      VFUN VARCHAR2(200);
      VESTADO_MENSAJES NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      VID := ID_UNICO;
      VID_TOKEN := 'TESTTOKEN';
      VID_USUARIO := 'ADM';
      VFEC_CREACION := FECHA_CREACION;
      VFEC_EXPIRACION := FECHA_EXPIRACION;
      VUSU := 'LNICOLAA';
      VFUN := 'LNICOLAA';

      USR_SP_TOKEN.CREAR(
        VID => VID,
        VID_TOKEN => VID_TOKEN,
        VID_USUARIO => VID_USUARIO,
        VFEC_CREACION => VFEC_CREACION,
        VFEC_EXPIRACION => VFEC_EXPIRACION,
        VUSU => VUSU,
        VFUN => VFUN,
        VESTADO_MENSAJES => VESTADO_MENSAJES
      );

       VESTADO_MENSAJES := VESTADO_MENSAJES;
    --rollback; 
    --USR_SP_TOKEN_CREAR;         
    END;
    
END;
```

It throws me this kind of error that I can't find the way to solve  :

```
ORA-06550: line 29, column 21:
PLS-00371: at most one declaration for 'FECHA_CREACION' is permitted
ORA-06550: line 29, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 30, column 23:
PLS-00371: at most one declaration for 'FECHA_EXPIRACION' is permitted
ORA-06550: line 30, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I'm trying to create Global Variables to give them to a group of procedures , but I'm having this problem with this one in specific.

Comment: You can not use DECLARE inside BEGIN. There should be only one DECLARE for pl/sql anonymous block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear.  You have two different declarations for the same variable

```
  FECHA_CREACION DATE;
  <<several lines removed>>
  FECHA_CREACION DATE := to_date('2020-01-19','yyyy-MM-dd');
```

The first line declares a variable `FECHA_CREACION`.  The second line declares a variable of the same name and initializes it.  You'd need to remove one of the lines.  I assume you want to remove the first.  Note that you have similar problems with other variables as well-- `FECHA_EXPIRACION` for example.